# SQL Server restore backup error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I try to restore a SQL Server 2008 r2 backup I got this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\erp_20118110.bak'. Operating
>   system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

What is this mean ??

Comment: The problem was permissions guys, thanks - I gave the backup file permission to "Everyone" now i can restore it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what my Google-fu tells me, "error 5" is "Access Denied", hence I suppose that an account SQL Server is running under (not *you* yourself) doesn't have access to the specified backup file.

As a sidenote: it's generally a bad practice to keep backups under "Program Files".